# How does Python if and isinstance work in this example?

Tags: python

I am a relative Python newbie (so apologies for what is probably a stupid question) - I need to look through the elements list below and print the first element of each list if it is an integar - I must admit I can't completely understand solution#1 doesn't work and why solution#2 does:

```
elements = [
    [1, 4, 6, 7],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [6, 7, 8],
    [],
    ["nodata", "nodata"],
    [1, 3]
            ]
```

solution#1:

```
for i in elements:
    if isinstance(i[0], int):     #  check if first element of each list is an int
        print(i[0])
```

(I get an list index out of range error, but not sure why - is it because one of the lists is empty?? - this seems to be the case as this works:

```
for i in elements:
    if len(i) > 0 and isinstance(i[0], int):
        print(i[0])
```

solution#2:

```
for i in elements:
    if i and isinstance(i[0], int):     # what does 'if i and ....' mean here?? does it mean 'if i is not empty' and???
        print(i[0])
```

Thanks a lot for any help in advance!

Comment: Yes it's because the list is empty, it's just i[0] which is failing because there is no 0 element there.

Comment: Completely unrelated title and question to the actual issue. I don't think it can be salvaged.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First you should use sensible names to your variables like `for sublist in elements:`

- Then, accessing an empty list with `sublist[0]` will raise an error as there is not box at `0`, the `len(sublist) > 0` fixes it
- `bool([])` gives `False` and `bool([1])` gives `True`, that why you can shorten the emptyness condition, these are equivalent :

  - `if len(sublist) > 0`
  - `if sublist`

Answer (score 1):

> I get an list index out of range error, but not sure why - is it because one of the lists is empty?? - this seems to be the case as this works:

Yes, when you do `for i in elements` `i` is taking on the value of each of values within `elements`.  In your example the 4th entry is an empty list so `i[0]` will have an index error

> what does 'if i and ....' mean here??

In python `if some_list` will return `True` if the list is not empty

Answer (score 1):

The first solution ends by an error as `i[0]` does not necessarily exists.
The second solution works well because it checks if `i[0]` exists by `if i` means: `if bool(i == True)`.